# Is there a close form solution for parallel transport on 2 sphere along the great circles.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I need to transport a tangent vector on 2-sphere from point $p$ to $q$ along the geodesic, which is defined using great circles in this case.
I believe there are iterative solutions to achieve that like explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401170/parallel-transport-along-a-2-sphere). Is there a close form solution to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you want to apply the unique rotation matrix that sends $p$ to $q$ while preserving their cross product. Computing that rotation matrix is a well-known problem, e.g.:

[Calculate Rotation Matrix to align Vector A to Vector B in 3d?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d)
[Stack Overflow: Finding quaternion representing the rotation from one vector to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171849/finding-quaternion-representing-the-rotation-from-one-vector-to-another)

Answer (score 3):

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\mathbf{e}}$Explicitly, assume $p$ and $q$ are distinct, non-antipodal unit vectors (points on the unit sphere in $\Reals^{3}$). Introduce the orthonormal basis
$$
\Basis_{1} = p,\qquad
\Basis_{3} = \frac{p \times q}{\|p \times q\|},\qquad
\Basis_{2} = \Basis_{3} \times \Basis_{1},
$$
and let $c = p \cdot q$, so that
$$
q = c \Basis_{1} + \sqrt{1 - c^{2}} \Basis_{2}.
$$

[image: Parallel transport on the unit sphere]

Under parallel transport along the great circle arc
$$
\gamma(t) = (\cos t) \Basis_{1} + (\sin t) \Basis_{2},
\tag{1}
$$
$\Basis_{2}$ (blue) is carried to $(\cos t) \Basis_{2} - (\sin t) \Basis_{1}$, while $\Basis_{3}$ (green) is preserved. Every tangent vector $v$ at $p$ (black) can be written as a linear combination
$$
v = a \Basis_{2} + b \Basis_{3},
$$
and the parallel transport of $v$ along (1) from $p$ to $\gamma(t)$ is
$$
\Gamma_{t}(v) = a(\cos t) \Basis_{2} - a(\sin t) \Basis_{1} + b \Basis_{3}.
$$
$\endgroup$